# UITableview Reusability issue when drawing a line on tableview cell and moving it to the end of the table

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have to make an application where I can add N number of rows in UITableview.This is how I am using **reusability**.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

        UITableViewCell *Cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if(Cell==nil)
        {
            Cell=[self tableViewCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath ofTableView:tableView];
        }

        [Cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone];
        [Cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

        [self ConfigureCell:Cell forIndexPath:indexPath forTableView:tableView];

        return Cell;
}
```

Then on **swipe right** I have to **draw a line and add button** on a particular cell of UITableview that I am doing in swipe gesture method after retrieving the UITableviewCell in that method and have to move cell to the bottom after adding the subviews.

```
CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:GroupedTableView];

    NSIndexPath *IndexPath = [GroupedTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.GroupedTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:IndexPath];

  UIButton *CrossButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        CrossButton.frame=CGRectMake(250, 12, 15, 15);
        [CrossButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        CrossButton.tag=800+IndexPath.row;
        [CrossButton addTarget:self action:@selector(CrossButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:CrossButton];

        UIImageView *LineImage=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
        LineImage.frame=CGRectMake(10, 19, 220, 2);
        LineImage.tag=700+IndexPath.row;
        LineImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"line.png"];
        LineImage.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:LineImage];


 NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:RowNum inSection:0];

    [self.GroupTableContentArray insertObject:[self.GroupTableContentArray objectAtIndex:IndexPath.row] atIndex:lastIndexPath.row+1];

    [self.GroupTableContentArray removeObjectAtIndex:IndexPath.row];

    [self.GroupedTableView moveRowAtIndexPath:IndexPath toIndexPath:lastIndexPath];
```

This also works fine till the table height is small but once it is bigger than the screen size and I scroll to see the bottom content,the line I have drawn on that particular cell vanishes and sometimes its visible on other cell which was not marked.I know this is the issue of reusability but I am unable to figure out a way.

My requirement is like any.Do app where we swipe right to select a finished task and put it at the bottom of the table.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you don't quite understand how table view cell reuse works.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Asks the table delegate for a cell that is going to be displayed at the specified index path. You ask the table view for a reusable cell with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. Now, if the returned cell is nil it is your job to create a new cell.

When setting cell properties like text, detail text and image, you have to treat each cell as if it has unwanted data, meaning that you should overwrite everything each time before returning  a cell.

To give you an example of this, imagine you have a table view with 10 visible cells and a 100 rows. Your first cell has "Hello world" in it and the other ones are empty. Now, when you start scrolling you are going to be seeing "Hello world" every 10 or so cells. This is happening because a random available cell is being returned from the tables reusable cell queue which has kept all of its changes like text, images, and subviews.

And that is also what is happening to your cell with the line and the button, so to avoid this, appropriate properties should be set for each index path. The problem is that you are adding subviews to your cell with no reference to them so they cannot be removed or hidden easily and so are always visible at random index paths. Furthermore you're going to get in a situation where you have multiple lines and buttons in the same cell.

It would be best for you to create a UITableViewCell subclass where each cell has its own line and button which can be shown/hidden as necessary for each index path.

Comment: I got the answer other way around but this concept of reusability helped me though.Thanks.